# bc command in UNIX - number system conversion

Tags: shell, unix

I am using `bc` command to make system number conversion.
From decimal to binary, binary to HEX, and HEX to decimal.
But I have a problem with it.

This is the problem:

```
memam@mSolaris:~$ bc
ibase=2 
obase=16
1111
17
```

Why the output doesn't appear correctly?
The output must be `F`?

And when I use ibase=16 and obase=2, it works correctly.
When I change the `ibase=10` and `obase=2`, it works correctly.

```
ibase=10
obase=2
3 
11
```

but this is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the `obase` first so that it doesn't try to interpret the value with the radix specified in `ibase`.

```
$ bc
obase=16
ibase=2
1111
F
```

Or, well...

```
$ bc
ibase=2
obase=10000
1111
F
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have them; the example in your question gives me a *completely different answer*.

Comment: `$ bc`
`ibase=2`
`obase=16`
`1111`
`120`

Comment: I also have `120`. This is probably due to differing `bc` versions. Anyway, we cannot blame `bc` for not understanding what `16` means in binary.