# Why do we use echo and bc together?

Tags: bash, shell

In Shell scripting (Linux/Ubuntu , Bash) , why do we use echo and bc commands together ? I am new to Shell scripting and have a basic understanding of pipes .
I know that bc is kind of a seperate language . How does the following statement actually work (Just an example) ?
    `echo 5+6 | bc`

Comment: Just a note: If you want to multiply 2 numbers, make sure that you escape the `*` operator as `\*`. Else `echo *` will expand it as wildcard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  There are many resources on the Internet that can help you learn shell scripting.  This site is more geared towards specific questions and answers relating to programming.  If you are having trouble with code, post it here.  But if you're looking for more general help about bash programming, try the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), the [bash man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports) and [some of the other resources on the Internet](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bash+guide).

Comment: @anishsane I dont think we need to use escape characters in bc . I dont know why we need not use , but it works without escaping the *'s and other such 'special' characters

Comment: We don't need escapes in bc, but while echoing (say `echo 4 * 5 | bc`) you need to escape the `*`.

Comment: @anishsane .. There is no need .. `echo 4*5|bc` works perfectly fine

Comment: Try this:
`cd /tmp; touch 41235; echo 4*5|bc`. It fails to do what you were expecting it to do. It works, only after escaping *.

Comment: @anishsane Yeah .. U r right . It doesn't work as expected -_-

Comment: explanation: When bash gives arguments to echo, it tries to expand them by default. So 4*5 would get expanded to whatever file/s is/are present & that will match the wildcard expansion 4*5 (41235 in our example) Another alternate option is to 'quote' `'4*5'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that program combination for another set of powerful operations, for example you can convert from hexadecimal to binary like this

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; A15" | bc
```

It will print: `101000010101`

As for the process of echoing and using the `|` operator, it just make the output of the `echo`command an input for the `bc` program, you can achieve the same using for example: `bc <<< "5 + 2"`

`bc` does not read operations from command line arguments, instead it reads it from an input file or in an interactive session

Another example of this useful combination is the calculation of really big quantities, like:

```
echo "2^1024" | bc
```

**A note about the `<<<`:** it passes a string on a single line as an input file to the command, if the program reads its input from a file, with `<<<` you can convert a string to a "file" and then pass this "file" to the program.

Comment: bc <<< '5+2' works ! What is this operator ? And what's happening here . Can you elaborate a little ?

Comment: Thanks for enlightening about <<<

Comment: While your first example is perfectly fine, you might want to swap the definitions of `ibase` and `obase`: otherwise, `obase` is interpreted in the new `ibase`, so that `ibase=16; obase=10; A15` will result in `A15`, not in `2581`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861888/bc-command-in-unix-number-system-conversion) for more details.

Comment: **Please stop useless pipe!** Syntax  `echo 3+2|bc` implie one *fork*! While `bc <<<3+2` don't! In this special case, this won't be very different because `echo` is a *builtin*. But please, try to compare: `time for i in {0..2000};do result=$(bc <<<2+3);done` and `time for i in {0..2000};do result=$(echo 2+3|bc);done`

Comment: @higuaro I should have said in the comment to my edit of your answer that an unquoted string must appear only on the line with `<<<`. A quoted string can start on the `<<<` line and end on a subsequent line. It's very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

The first command (`echo`)  writes the expression "5+6" to its standard output. This is then piped to `bc`'s standard input, read from there, and evaluated.

This is used since `bc` doesn't take the expression as a direct input, it always reads from files and/or standard input.

Comment: "This is used since bc doesn't take the expression as a direct input, it always reads from files and/or standard input" .. Makes the answer 100% complete . Thanks :) Is there any reason it works the way it does ?

Answer (score 3):

echo is not required here and can be replaced by an here document:

```
bc <<%
5+6
%
```

or with modern shells:

```
bc <<< 5+6
```

Comment: As `%` could be used for *modulo*, this could be not the best choice for `EOF` tag.

Comment: @F.Hauri Using "%" would have no effect as being an operator, it doesn't appear alone on its line. This is mandatory for an here document terminator to be identified as such.

Comment: @F.Hauri Granted, what would you suggest as best choice?

Comment: I've tried `$` wich work even if a line begin with `$RANDOM` for sample, but it's a joke. Seriously, I like to use explicit tags when I use *here documents*, like `bc <<- eoBcFourAddedToFive` (and use tabulation to indent *bc* part of script) all this make the script a lot more readable, mostly if you use many *here documents*.

Comment: @F.Hauri Nested here documents are not that common. I would stick with % or %EOF% for usual cases.

Answer (score 0):

Before **bc** command we can see very simple PIPE:

```
|
```

The name **pipe** is very accurate! Like a normal pipe this one is transferring water from source to target. In computer science water is called *data* or *information*.

Like every good pipe, both endings of it are special. Through those endings we can connect pipe to other pipes, taps, joints, etc.

One ending of this pipe is connected to *bc* which has matching ending. *Bc* is a big piece of software, so it has many different connection points for different pipes. Also for this simple **|** pipe.

On the other hand **5+6** is not any piece of software. It is pure data/water. You can imagine what will happen if you pure water to one end of the pipe without fixed connection! Lack of water pressure...

We need some software which has good connection to that pipe. **Echo** is very simple application, doing practically nothing, like decent echo should do... But it has basic and functional ending matching that simple pipe.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of text formatting

```
  echo -n "pi=" ; bc -l <<< "scale=10; 4*a(1)"
```

pi=3.1415926532